# NodeJS - Different results when generating hash from stream vs local file

Tags: javascript, node.js

It seems like if I hash a file stream I get a different hash than if I write the stream to disk, read it back and then hash it. Possibly an encoding issue or I'm wrong that the hashes SHOULD be the same?

Here's my test case

```
const fs = require("fs");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const https = require("https");

(async ()=>{
  const testUrl = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/SIPI_Jelly_Beans_4.1.07.tiff/lossy-page1-256px-SIPI_Jelly_Beans_4.1.07.tiff.jpg"
  const filePath = "./testFile.jpg";

  https.get(testUrl, async function(response) {

    await writeFile(filePath, response);
    
    const streamHash = await hashFileStream(response)
    const fileHash = await hashLocalFile(filePath)
    
    console.log("Stream Hash", streamHash);
    console.log("File hash", fileHash);

  });

})()

async function writeFile(filePath, stream) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const file = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
    stream.pipe(file)
    .on('finish', () => {
      resolve(filePath);
    })
    .on('error', (error)=>{
      console.error(error);
      reject(error);
    })
  })
}
  
async function hashFileStream(stream){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    const hash = crypto.createHash('md5').setEncoding('hex');
    stream.pipe(hash)
    .on('finish', ()=>{
      resolve(hash.read())
    })
    .on('error', (error)=>{
      reject(error)
    })
  })
}

async function hashLocalFile(filepath){
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
  return hashFileStream(readStream);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is your mistake. According to node js documents :

> The 'finish' event is emitted after the stream.end() method has been called, and all data has been flushed to the underlying system.

When finish event emitted in `writeFile` function then stream is done writing data and nothing remains for `hashFileStream` function.

If you want to just check hash strings, the easiest way is to separate the code and will see they are same:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const https = require("https");

(async ()=>{
  const filePath = "./testFile.jpg";
  const testUrl = "https://static2.farakav.com/files/pictures/watermark/01661368.jpg"


  https.get(testUrl, async function(response) {

    await writeFile(filePath, response);
    const fileHash = await hashLocalFile(filePath)
    
    console.log("File hash", fileHash);

  });

  https.get(testUrl, async function(response) {
        const streamHash = await hashFileStream(response)    
        console.log("Stream Hash", streamHash);    
      });

})()


async function writeFile(filePath, stream) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const file = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
    stream.pipe(file)
    .on('finish', () => {
      resolve(filePath);
    })
    .on('error', (error)=>{
      console.error(error);
      reject(error);
    })
  })
}
  
async function hashFileStream(stream){

  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    const hash = crypto.createHash('md5').setEncoding('hex');
    stream.pipe(hash)
    .on('finish', ()=>{
        hash.end();
      resolve(hash.read())
    })
    .on('error', (error)=>{
      reject(error)
    })
  })
}

async function hashLocalFile(filepath){
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);

  return hashFileStream(readStream);
}
```